# Importing ES6 code from node modules not working in jest

Tags: webpack, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I have created a component library in react which exports all its component in ES6 modules.

For this I have used **@babel/plugin-transform-runtime** with the below configuration

```
{
   "corejs": 2,
    "helpers": true,
    "regenerator": true,
    "useESModules": true
 }
```

but when i am importing these modules and trying to execute my test case. It throw the following error.

```
Test suite failed to run

C:\<project-path>\node_modules\@babel\runtime-corejs2\helpers\esm\extends.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import _Object$assign from "../../core-js/object/assign";
                                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/<component-library-path>/Anchor.js:1:1)
```

Can someone please have a look into it.